# How can i add some key values in existing yaml file in php symfony

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

I have one YAML file like this

```
  category: 'test'
  available: true
  class: true
  name: 'john'
  children:
    -
      id: fdfd5
      f2: 30
```

Now before that name field i  want to add one more file like

`displayname = This is your $name` where $name is name from same category.

This is what i am thinkling of

```
//read
$yaml = Yaml::parse(file_get_contents('/path/to/file.yml'));


//code here    

//write
$dumper = new Dumper();

$yaml = $dumper->dump($array);

file_put_contents('/path/to/file.yml', $yaml);
```

How can i get $array to what i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uh, I think this will work (don't have a VM nearby so I can't test it)

```
$yaml = array_merge(
    array('displayname' => "This is your $name")
  , Yaml::parse(file_get_contents('/path/to/file.yml'))
);

file_put_contents('/path/to/file.yml', Yaml::dump($yaml));
```

Or you could always make [your own configuration class](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/definition.html)